# Facebook API - Get friends hometown

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Im looking to retrieve all of my friends hometowns, I am using similar PHP as that used to retrieve their names. I think the code im using *should* work but I think because some users havent set a hometown it wont work and says the for each argument is invalid (although this could be completely wrong).

When simply typing in the URL to the web browser I get the following structure:

```
{
   "id": "z",
   "friends": {
      "data": [
        {
            "name": "x",
            "hometown": {
               "id": "x",
               "name": "x"
            },
            "id": "x"
         },
```

Which is then repeated for every user in the friend list, although for friends without a hometown the following is omitted:

```
"hometown": {
             "id": "x",
             "name": "x"
                },
```

To retrieve the name and birthday I have used the following PHP:

---

```
$response2 = curl_exec($ch2);
$user2 = json_decode($response2, true);
$user3=$user2{'friends'};
$user4=$user3['data'];
echo ("<h2>Friend List</h2><br>");
foreach($user4 as $friend) {
    echo $friend["name"] . "<br />" . $friend["birthday"] . "<br /><br />";
    }
}
```

PS I know the variable names arent particularly good but I will change them once ive figured out what im doing for the hometown!

Thanks a lot for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Not everyone makes their hometown or location available to their friends. In that case you won't be able to get the data over the API and need to check for that.

To get a bit more data than just querying for the hometown, we also read out the current_location.

Through the Graph API you would use this resource: `https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?fields=hometown,location`

If you are using FQL you can use a query like this:

```
SELECT uid, first_name, last_name, current_location, hometown_location, friend_count, mutual_friend_count FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())
```

Remember that you need the `friends_location` and `friends_hometown` permission to read these fields.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, from my understanding you cannot access the users location or hometown by using `me/friends/` and you have to use `user_id?fields=friends`
Im not using FQL but wouldnt be averse to using it so long as the hometown is returned, the idea is then to display the hometown in Google Maps

Comment: /me/friends will return both location and hometown if you ask for the fields in the query string. You can check it out in the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%2Ffriends%3Ffields%3Dname%2Chometown%2Clocation). (Press "Get Access Token" and give the `friends_location` and `friends_hometown` permissions.)

Comment: By the way, if you're using the hometown for Google Maps, you can use the ID returned by Facebook and make another query to get the latitude and longitude of the returned location. Example for Venice: [https://graph.facebook.com/110339052328061](https://graph.facebook.com/110339052328061)